# Compare two columns - get only unique values from second column

Tags: excel, compare, field, unique, unique-values

I'm looking for a tool/script that could help me to get only unique values when comparing two columns, and only unique values from second column. For example, if data is:

column1:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

column2:

```
aab
bb
ccd
```

In this case I would like to see in outcome 'aab and ccd' values, because it doesn't exist in column1. Excel seems to me doesn't have this exact functionality.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid only for Excel 365.

With duplicates within both columns **A** and **B** as well as duplication between the columns, in **C1** enter:

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(B1:B16),COUNTIF(A1:A20,UNIQUE(B1:B16))=0)
```

[image]

If your version of Excel is older, I would use a "helper" column.